# $\lim_{N\to\infty}1/N\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n\alpha)=\int_0^1f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $R^1$ with period 1. Prove that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n\alpha)=\int_0^1f(t)dt$$
>   for every irrational number $\alpha$. Hint: Do it first for $$f(t)=e^{2πikt}$$

How are these two thing connected? Intuitively the left hand side is acting like a Riemann sum but it isn't a Riemann sum. $n\alpha$ is fairly ambiguous and hard to understand. In the long run  I understand that $(n\alpha)$ (the decimal value of $n\alpha$) populates the entire interval $(0,1$ fairly uniformly. I don't understand how that may help. I don't know any assistance

Comment: Are you able to show that it's true for $f(t) = e^{2\pi i k t}$ as the hint suggests?

Comment: This might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset .

Comment: also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033021/proof-of-lim-limitsm-to-infty-frac1m-sum-limitsn-1m-fan-int-limits?rq=1

Comment: and to a lesser extent https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517953/how-prove-this-nice-limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-k-1nf-ka?rq=1

Comment: @TrevorGunn Your second link is a better candidate than the first. The answer to the first has a problem, as noted in the associated comment.

Comment: @Bungo is right, if you're looking at the first link, note that you should approximate your continuous function uniformly by trigonometric polynomials instead of trying to take a Fourier series.